# innerHTML not receiving value from fetch function

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I have a simple api fetch that is returning a number that I want to insert into an input. I am using document.getElementById(#id).innerHTML. I can see the value via console.log but it doesn't show up in the input.

```
    <div>
      <input type="number" name="AtBats" id="atBats" value="" />
    </div>

    <script>
      const player_url =
        'http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.sport_hitting_tm.bam?league_list_id=%27mlb%27&game_type=%27R%27&season=%272017%27&player_id=%27592450%27';
      
async function getNums() {
        const response = await fetch(player_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        let output = data.sport_hitting_tm.queryResults.row.ab;
        console.log(output);
        document.getElementById('atBats').innerHTML = output;
        console.log(atBats)
      }

      getNums();
```

Comment: `input` elements such as this do not have an `innerHTML` property - you want to set the `value` ~ ie: `document.getElementById('atBats').value= output;`

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign innerHTML to an input element since it doesn't have it. Value and innterHTML are not same things. You can do like this to change value;

```
document.getElementById('atBats').value= output;
```